# Golang writing to a socket without worrying about incomplete data

Tags: sockets, go, io

We all know that that the Write method does not guarantee writing tall the bytes from the buffer. Therefore the canonical way of writing bytes to a asocket using the raw Write method is like so

```
//how many bytes we have written
written := 0 

for written < len(msg){
    //write the bytes from buffer that havent been witten yet
    wr, err := conn.Write(msg[written:])

    if err != nil{
        return;
    }

    written += wr
}
```

Now let's say I dont want to use such low-level techniques and want to use a function that does this for me. Which function from the standard library should I use?

Comment: “We all know that that the Write method does not guarantee writing tall the bytes from the buffer”, no we don’t all know that, because it’s not true. From the docs:`Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The canonical way to write bytes to a socket is:

```
_, err := conn.Write(msg)
if err != nil{
    // handle error
}
```

A loop is unnecessary because Write returns a non-nil error when Write stops before writing all of the slice data.

Write is different from Read in this regard. Read can succeed without filling the slice.

Comment: I don't see this in the documentation. net.Conn is an interface, documented as
```
// Write writes data to the connection.
// Write can be made to time out and return an error after a fixed
// time limit; see SetDeadline and SetWriteDeadline.
Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```
The io.Writer interface also doesn't say anything about returning an error if the full buffer isn't written.

What you say *may be true* about the current implementation, but that doesn't make it a guarantee. OP is looking for a guarantee.

Comment: @SAyotte The [io.Writer documentation](https://godoc.org/io#Writer) says *Write writes len(p) bytes from p to the underlying data stream. It returns the number of bytes written from p (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered that caused the write to stop early. Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p).* In other words, Write must return a non-nil error when the full slice is not written.